# Why does the load() function with [] as the second argument not run on mount unless I pass in [load] to the second argument?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

Why does the `load()` function with `[]` as the second argument not run on mount unless I pass in `[load]` to the second argument? I do not want to pass in the second argument as I only want the `load()` function to run once on mount and never afterward. How do I achieve this?

```
const HoursTimer = (props) => {
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(null);
    const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        load();
    }, [])

    function load() {
        props.hours.forEach((hour, i) => {
            if (i === (props.hours.length-1)) {
                setIsActive(hour.clockedIn)
                setActiveId(hour._id)
            }
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>{isActive}</p>
            <p>{activeId}</p>
        </div>
    );
};

function mapStateToProps( { hours } ) {
    return { hours };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchHours })(HoursTimer);
```

Comment: All `useEffect` hooks run on mount, *and* when any values in their dependency array update. How do you know it isn't triggering the effect when the component mounts, i.e. how are you validating this assertion?

Comment: if I use `, [load])` then `<p>{isActive}</p>` `<p>{activeId}</p>` shows the correct values

Comment: Yes, `load` sets some state values that won't be rendered until the next render cycle, i.e. the second cycle, the one *after* the component mounts. You know you can provide initial state to the `useState` hooks. It's also a bit of an anti-pattern to store props in state.

Comment: Your code works fine as per your expectation and I could run it. Make sure your redux state is in proper order. This code runs load function only once and then it renders and display ```isActive``` and ```activeId``` values, which of the last element of hours list.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used React before, but a quick review of the useEffect source, and I think I have and answer for you.

useEffect takes two arguments, as you know. But did you know the array, aka "deps" tells React, when you want to rerun the effect? React does this by "rechecking" those deps.

So a short hand for run once, but never again is an empty array.

I confirmed this from React's [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html)

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
> unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
> tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
> or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
> case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
> works.

> If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect
> will always have their initial values. While passing [] as the second
> argument is closer to the familiar componentDidMount and
> componentWillUnmount mental model, there are usually better solutions
> to avoid re-running effects too often. Also, don’t forget that React
> defers running useEffect until after the browser has painted, so doing
> extra work is less of a problem.

Another insightful comment from the documentation

> The array of dependencies is not passed as arguments to the effect
> function. Conceptually, though, that’s what they represent: **every
> value referenced inside the effect function** should also appear in the
> dependencies array. In the future, a sufficiently advanced compiler
> could create this array automatically.

So depending on you desired behavior, if you want to run the effect, everytime the prop.hours updated you might need to do something like

```
useEffect(() => {
    load();
}, [props.hours])

function load() {
    props.hours.forEach((hour, i) => {
        if (i === (props.hours.length-1)) {
            setIsActive(hour.clockedIn)
            setActiveId(hour._id)
        }
    })
}
```

Looking into things a bit more, I found this [article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/), which may be helpful.

As for you question:

> Why does the load() function with [] as the second argument not run on
> mount unless I pass in [load]

I suspect, it's because [load] is a function, which react, will rerun, but
it's doing so to check if it needs to rerun the effect... with the side effect, of well, having already, rerun load, which just so happens to be your entire useEffect. -- that was at least 3 levels of inception.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It wouldn't really make sense to specify `load` as a dependency, because it's declared inside the component function body. As such, the reference is guaranteed to change each time the component renders.

Comment: I agree, and I'm not suggesting to put [load] as a dep, [props.hours], perhaps, depending on the desired life-cycle.